# Spring mvc tag question

Tags: spring-mvc

What is the significance 'label' and 'path' in the spring mvc jsp tag:

```
form:label path="someName"
```

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

label simply defines the text of the field within the page, for example:

```
<form:select path="dataVisArray"><br />
     <form:option label="Select..." value=""/>
     <form:options items="${dataVisArray} itemLabel="label" itemValue="value"/>
</form:select>
```

shows a dropdown, where the first element is "Select..." and the rest is defined in ${dataVisArray}

path links to a form backing object where you can save the input. In the example above, there would be a variable called "dataVisArray" within the backing object to save the value of the selected item once the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

The label attribute is for displaying text corresponding to the form element for which we are using the label attribute

```
<label for="FirstName" >First Name :</label>
```

For Path attribute can be also used in validation of form element by jquery

```
<form:input path="name" id="name" name="name"/>
```

The path value name then can be used for validation purpose:

```
$("#ajaxForm").validate({
     rules: {
         name: {
                required:true,
                minlenght:3

            },
      messages: {
            name : {
            required : 'Enter Username',
            maxlength :'Not more than 30 Charachters',
            minlength :'Should be more than 3 characters'
        },
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring MVC JSP tag **lable** signifies the value to be displayed as part of the tag and **path** is used to signify path to property for data binding.

```
<form:label path="company"> Enter company name: </form:label>
```